# How to fill out a PDF form and support multiple languages in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, character-encoding, itext, pdf-form

I wanted to know if there is a way to support multiple languages when filling out a form field with iTextSharp.  We need to support user’s filling out fields in English, European languages with diacritics, and Asian languages like Chinese and Japanese, but do not know how to support these all on the same PDF (e.g. the user could have form fields that are answered in English and some in Chinese for example).  We have to work with Acrobat forms that are pre-defined, e.g. we cannot create a PDF completely from scratch in our scenario.

Is there a way to accomplish this within iTextSharp?  At least to support most European languages and Chinese and for the form/generation process to know when to use the right know that support the particular character(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to dynamically generate the PDF based on user inputs from another program, e.g. a windows forms app or a web page?  Based on the user's selection from said app you could dynamically generate the PDF (based on a template) and apply the appropriate character sets.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an option for this process.  I can edit the PDF forms, create duplicates with form fields, etc., but they have to be the original forms instead of generating a PDF from scratch (e.g. building the layout, PDF, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you would generate the entire PDF from scratch.  What I meant when I said "based on a template" was that you would programmatically load that template (a .pdf, or .html) file,  then populate the fields with their values using the proper language as selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The problem you're having (best guess) is that the pre-defined fonts for the fields you're filling use WinAnsiEncoding (or some other mono-byte encoding that doesn't support all the diacritics you need).

And I see that iText does support setting a field's font directly.  Excellent.

```
myAcroFields.setFieldProperty(fldName, "textfont", myBaseFont, null);
```

I believe you're required to subset fonts with Chinese encodings, but for the European-encoded fonts you probably want to fully embed the font in question.  Fonts in form fields (that can be edited) react poorly when you try to display a missing character... at least they used to, many moons ago.  Last time I tried was around Acrobat 5, so it's quite likely that the behavior has improved.